# SoQL parent to child (and vice versa) queries are driving me nuts. Need super help to understand

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, lookup, relationships

A custom object B has a custom field, which is a Lookup on custom object A.

So this means that for each B there can be only ONE A, yes? And multiple B's can have same A, or a single A can have multiple B's related to it, correct?

[Basic SOQL relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html)

From above, I'm doing :

```
SELECT A__c.Id, A__c.Name, (SELECT B__c.Id, B__c.Name FROM B__c) FROM A__c
```

It is **NOT** working.

And ofc the code below wont even work, right?

```
SELECT Id, Name, A__c.Id, A__c.Name FROM B__c
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am completely out of my depth here. Complex SOQL relationships hurt my brain just thinking about them.

**EDIT :**

The field on object B__c reads :

`Related object - Related_object__c - Lookup(object)`

I tried

`SELECT A__r.Id, A__r.Name, (SELECT B__r.Name FROM B__c) FROM A__c`

but yet again, its not working.

Comment: It's __r, not __c. There's tons of questions about this already. See if that helps you?

Comment: I tried `SELECT A__r.Id, A__r.Name, (SELECT B__r.Name FROM B__c) FROM A__c` but yet again, its not working.  'Related object Related_object__c Lookup(object)` I replaced the actual name with "object". But I do hope you understood how this is structured.

Comment: `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM B__r) FROM A__c` sounds more like what you're looking for?

Comment: You need to use plural relationship names. In your case you need to use Bs__r. Please see the answer below

Comment: Worked, sorta. `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Bs__r) FROM A__c`. Mind making it an answer, SFDCFox? Also, WHY is SoQL so confusing!?!?!?!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the relationship name when using parent-child soql queries.

```
SELECT A__c.Id, A__c.Name, (SELECT B__c.Id, B__c.Name FROM Bs__r) FROM A__c
```

please refer this link to understand the relationships in a better way.

[Understanding Relationship Names](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)

Comment: Worked, sorta. `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Bs__r) FROM A__c`.

Comment: A problem : `common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: B__c.Related_object__r `. I tried the query in force.com explorer AND workbench and it DOES return the related object name + object...

Comment: This error comes when we use a field without including it into SOQL. Check if there is any and then add them into your SOQL.

Answer (score 1):

- **Parent To Child:**
- select id, (select id from contacts) from account - For standard relationship
- select id, (select id from Child_Relationship_Name__r) from customobject__c - For custom relationship
- **Child To Parent**
- select id, Account.name from contact - For standard relationship
- select id, customobject__r.name from customobject__c - For custom relationship